# Show that $\widehat{(0,1)}$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]/\sim$ where $x\sim y\iff x=y\text{ or }\{x,y\}=\{0,1\}$.

Tags: general-topology

$\widehat{(0,1)}=(0,1)\cup\{p\}$, where $p\not\in(0,1)$. A set $U$ in $\widehat{(0,1)}$ is open iff ($U\not\ni p$ and $U$ is open in $(0,1)$) or ($U\ni p$ and $(0,1)\setminus U$ is a compact subset of $(0,1)$).

> Show that $\widehat{(0,1)}$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1]/\sim$ where $x\sim y\iff x=y\text{ or }\{x,y\}=\{0,1\}$.

A set of representatives of $[0,1]/\sim=\{[x]\mid x\in[0,1] \}$ is $\bigcup_{x\in(0,1)}\underbrace{[x]}_{=\{x\}}\cup \underbrace{[0]}_{=[1]=\{0,1\}}$.

Let $p:[0,1]\twoheadrightarrow [0,1]/\sim:x\mapsto [x]$ be the quotient map, then $U\subset[0,1]/\sim$ is open iff $p^{-1}(U)\subset [0,1]$ is open.

I have to prove that
$$\begin{align*}f\colon[0,1]/\sim&\longrightarrow\widehat{(0,1)} \\ [x]&\longmapsto x\text{ if }x\in(0,1) \\ [0]=[1]&\longmapsto p  \end{align*}$$

is a homeomorphism.

It is clear that it is a bijection. I run into trouble when proving that it is continuous.

Let $U\subset\widehat{(0,1)}$ open. Assume $p\not\in U$, then $U$ is open in $(0,1)$, thus $U=(0,1)\cap B$ ($B$ open in $\mathbf{R}$). Then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $[0,1]/\sim$, since $p^{-1}(f^{-1}(U))=U$, which is open in $[0,1]$, since $U=\underbrace{((0,1)\cap B)}_{\text{open in }\mathbf{R}}\cap [0,1]$.

Now assume $p\in U$. Then $(0,1)\setminus U$ is a compact subset of $(0,1)$ (I assume this means by Heine Borel that it is closed in $(0,1)$?). So $(0,1)\setminus U=(0,1)\cap C$ ($C$ closed in $\mathbf{R}$). Now $(0,1)\setminus((0,1)\setminus U)=(0,1)\cap \underbrace{(\mathbf{R}\setminus C)}_{\text{open in }\mathbf{R}}$. This means that $p^{-1}(f^{-1}(U))$ is the union of some open subset of $(0,1)$ and $\{0,1\}$, which is not open in $[0,1]$.

I think this problem is difficult for me, because I don't feel familiar with the quotient topology yet. Could someone provide any help or an easier way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid calling your map $p,$ since $p$ already means something else. Let's go with $g,$ instead.

Now, you handled the $p\in U$ case optimally. For the $p\notin U$ case, we can proceed similarly. Let $K=(0,1)\setminus U,$ which does, indeed, mean that $K$ is closed in $\Bbb R.$ Noting that $$g^{-1}\bigl[f^{-1}[K]\bigr]=K,$$ so that $$g^{-1}\bigl[f^{-1}[U]\bigr]=[0,1]\setminus K=[0,1]\cap\underbrace{(\Bbb R\setminus K)}_{\text{open in }\Bbb R},$$ we have that $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in $[0,1]/\sim,$ as desired.

Let me know if you're unsure why any of these equalities must hold, or even if you just want to check if your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Why does $K$ compact in $(0,1)$ mean closed in $\mathbf{R}$?

Comment: Since $K$ is compact in $(0,1),$ then noting that the set $$\left\{\left(\frac1{n+2},\frac{n}{n+2}\right):n\in\Bbb N\right\}$$ covers $(0,1),$ and so covers $K,$ then it has a finite subcover. Thus, there is some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $K\subseteq\left[\frac1{n+2},\frac{n}{n+2}\right].$ Since $K$ is relatively closed in $(0,1)$ as the complement of a relatively open set, then it is relatively closed in $\left[\frac1{n+2},\frac{n}{n+2}\right],$ and so closed in $\Bbb R.$

Comment: Another more general result (that's a good exercise to prove) is this: If $Y$ is a subspace of $X,$ and $K\subseteq Y$ such that $K$ is compact in $Y,$ then $K$ is compact in $X.$ Thus, compactness in $(0,1)$ immediately yields compactness in $\Bbb R,$ and compact subsets of $\Bbb R$ (and other Hausdorff spaces) are closed.